# Should I use different Backbone classes or different instances for each list?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, architecture, frameworks, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js

I have multiple lists of models on my page. Should I just make one "class" with Backbone.Collection.extend and my lists should be instances of this "class", or should I make as many classes as I have model lists on my page?

So, should I do this:

```
var MyCol1 = new Backbone.Collection.extend({})
var MyCol2 = new Backbone.Collection.extend({})

var listView1 = new ItemsView({ collection: new MyCol1 })
var listView2 = new ItemsView({ collection: new MyCol2 })
```

or rather this?

```
var MyCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
var listView1 = new ItemsView({ collection: new MyCol })
var listView2 = new ItemsView({ collection: new MyCol })
```

Behavior of all lists will be pretty much the same at this point but they will have different backend urls they'll be attached to.

Comment: Do your two collections contain the same sorts of things?

Comment: Yes. Same sort of things. But different selection of things and in different arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is differente you will find you need two different classes, or you'll find your self in a hell of *conditional sentences*.

You can use a custom BaseCollection with the common behavior and inherit from it for the detailed behavior. Check things like:

- [How to create a base view in backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260264/how-to-create-a-base-view-in-backbone-js/12261832#12261832)
- [Proper way of doing view mixins in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853731/proper-way-of-doing-view-mixins-in-backbone)
- [Backbone.js view inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735133/backbone-js-view-inheritance)
- [Backbone View Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405828/backbone-view-inheritance)